# Wordpress - Order Custom Post Type By Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have the following piece of code:

```
$args = array( 'post_status'=>"publish", 
'posts_per_page' => 20,
'post_type'=>"equipment",
'orderby'=>"title",
'order'=>"ASC");

$postslist = get_posts( $args );

foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

This all works fine but what I would like to do is to be able to specify the order of the posts by the category within the custom taxonomy.

Is this possible?

Have been trying to use the category array but with no luck.

Just to give all the information, my custom taxonomy is called 'equipcats' and under here I have several categories, e.g. 'Visuals', 'Stage', 'Lighting', 'Sound'...

As it currently stands the order of the posts will be shown as alphabetically ascending so the order will be:

- Lighting
- Sound
- Stage
- Visuals

What I would like to do is to be able to have strict control over this ordering, so for example:

- Stage
- Visuals
- Lighting
- Sound

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the code below sets up filters to add a "join" clause to include the terms tables in the query, to restrict it to categories, and then to sort by the category ID. And then it re-queries, using the existing query variables (such as page number, etc.).

```
<?php   add_filter('posts_join', create_function('$a', 'global $wpdb; return $a . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) ";'));
        add_filter('posts_where', create_function('$a', 'global $wpdb; return $a . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = \'category\'";'));
        add_filter('posts_orderby', create_function('$a','global $wpdb; return "$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id DESC";'));
    query_posts('');
?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how would you integrate this into the current code?

Comment: Use query_posts(); function and then add these filters before executing the loop.